# Finding regions that include a point with MySQL

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial

I'm using MySQL GIS and Spatial Extensions.

I've a table with "circular" regions described by latitude, longitude and radius.

I need a query to get all the rows whose region include a given point defined by a latitude and a longitude. The "circular" regions can intersect and therefore the point can fall in more than one region.

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078386/see-if-lat-long-falls-within-a-polygon-using-mysql  The answer by Paul Dixon (which is basically that you can't do it using MySQL GIS functions) fits with my understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution and I would like to post it here just to have an opinion about it. Notice that the table structure above was slightly modified by adding a new column "location POINT" that is built using the latitude and the longitude at each insert.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetRequestsAroundLocation( IN lat DOUBLE, 
                                            IN lon DOUBLE )
BEGIN
  SET @answerLocation = GeomFromText( CONCAT( 'POINT( ', lat, ' ', lon, ' )' ) );

  SELECT id, token, latitude, longitude FROM Request 
  WHERE answerId = -1 AND 
        Intersects( @answerLocation, 
                    GeomFromText( CONCAT( 'POLYGON((', latitude - radius, ' ', longitude - radius, ',', 
                                                       latitude + radius, ' ', longitude - radius, ',', 
                                                       latitude + radius, ' ', longitude + radius, ',', 
                                                       latitude - radius, ' ', longitude + radius, ',', 
                                                       latitude - radius, ' ', longitude - radius, '))' ) ) ) AND 
        SQRT( POW( ABS( lat - latitude ), 2 ) + POW( ABS( lon - longitude ), 2 ) ) < radius;  
END //
```