# mysql GIS (point within polygon and near by points)

Tags: mysql, gis

I've seen this question: [See if lat / long falls within a polygon using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078386/see-if-lat-long-falls-within-a-polygon-using-mysql)

Which states that the mysql GIS extensions aren't fully implemented yet. Can someone clear this up for me - does this mean if I have a polygon stored and want to detect if a point falls within a certain polygon, it won't be 100% accurate? If so, how accurate will it be?

Also, the SQL required for this, off the top of my head, would it be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * WHERE WITHIN(POINT(_LAT_ _LONG_), `polygon`)
```

(Where polygon is a table column and the point is constructed from given lat and long values.)

If the accuracy is sufficient, how would you find points close to a given Lat and Long? There's differing opinions regarding using COS/SQRT or built in DISTANCE functions, which is best and/or what's the best method of doing?

Essentially:

- Are the mySQL GIS extensions up to the job for detecting if a point is within a polygon (has to be fairly accurate, polygon is not a defined shape or size).
- If they are, what is the best method for detecting this, and additionally want is the best method for finding points near a given Lat and Long

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/functions-that-test-spatial-relationships-between-geometries.html), all functions except Distance() and Related() only test MBR relationships.

> Currently, MySQL does not implement these functions according to the specification. Those that are implemented return the same result as the corresponding MBR-based functions. This includes functions in the following list other than Distance() and Related().

It's impossible to say whether accuracy of MBR tests is sufficient as this depends a lot on the shape of your polygons.

> "Are the mySQL GIS extensions up to the job for detecting if a point is within a polygon (has to be fairly accurate, polygon is not a defined shape or size)?"

**No.**

Use PostGIS if you can.

An alternative could be to implement a [Ray Casting algorithm for the Point-in-Polygon problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Comment: A small example: SELECT ASTEXT(location) FROM points
WHERE
WITHIN( location, GEOMFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON(( -81.19171 27.3090129,-81.19171 26.1525330,
-80.09308 26.1525330,-80.09308 27.3090129,-81.19171 27.3090129 ))'))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is fully implemented in the MySQL5.6.1 and above ([Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html)).

> MySQL originally implemented these functions such that they used
>   object bounding rectangles and returned the same result as the
>   corresponding MBR-based functions. **As of MySQL 5.6.1, corresponding
>   versions are available that use precise object shapes.** These versions
>   are named with an ST_ prefix. For example, Contains() uses object
>   bounding rectangles, whereas ST_Contains() uses object shapes.