# check lat/long position resides within a Polygon

Tags: php, mysql, geometry

i need to check if users lat and long resides in polygon.

my mysql version is 5.1.73

The Query i tried are as below

```
SET @g1 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((9.557417356841308 80.3155517578125, 7.993957436359008 79.7772216796875, 6.926426847059551 79.8101806640625, 6.206090498573886 80.1068115234375, 5.954826733929924 80.4254150390625, 6.446317749457659 81.7108154296875, 7.427836528738338 81.8426513671875, 8.309341443917633 81.3592529296875, 9.199715262283302 80.7879638671875, 9.438224391343347 80.4254150390625, 9.470735674130932 80.3155517578125))');

SET @g2 = ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POINT(6.89249389 80.8487013)');

SELECT ST_Intersects(@g1,@g2);
```

- i dont have ST_Intersect function in production DB, but i tried it in mariadb in local
- i tried ST_CONTAINS as well still the issue is same.

its resulting NULL. it should be 1 or 0 but. the polygon is covered the Sri Lanka country. and the users long and lat is also of a city in Sri Lanka.

When i do it using PHP, below is my function and it works without any trouble.

```
/**
 * to check if the given latitude and longitude reside inside the polygon coordinates
 * @param mixed $value The value to be checked
 * @$pointsPolygon number vertices - zero-based array
 * @$verticesX x-coordinates of the vertices of the polygon
 * @$verticesY y-coordinates of the vertices of the polygon
 * @$longitudeX longitude to check
 * @$latitudeY latitude to check
 * @return boolean
 */
function inPolygon($pointsPolygon,$verticesX,$verticesY,$longitudeX,$latitudeY)
{
    $i = $j = $c = 0;
    for($i = 0,$j = $pointsPolygon; $i < $pointsPolygon; $j = $i++){
        if((($verticesY[$i] > $latitudeY != ($verticesY[$j] > $latitudeY)) && ($longitudeX < ($verticesX[$j] - $verticesX[$i]) * ($latitudeY - $verticesY[$i]) / ($verticesY[$j] - $verticesY[$i]) + $verticesX[$i])))
            $c = !$c;
    }

    return $c;
}
```

function call

```
//sri lanka map zone
$turf = '[{"id":953,"color":"#32CD32","coordinates":[[9.557417356841308,80.3155517578125],
[7.993957436359008,79.7772216796875],[6.926426847059551,79.8101806640625],
[6.206090498573886,80.1068115234375],[5.954826733929924,80.4254150390625],
[6.446317749457659,81.7108154296875],[7.427836528738338,81.8426513671875],
[8.309341443917633,81.3592529296875],[9.199715262283302,80.7879638671875],
[9.438224391343347,80.4254150390625],[9.470735674130932,80.3155517578125]]}]'

$cordinates = $turfArr[0]['coordinates'];
$longLat = '-0.2710333,48.3490398';
$splitArr = explode(',' , $longLat);
$long = $splitArr[0];
$lat = $splitArr[1];
```

;

but i need to do it from the DB side.

Appreciate any leads.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ST_ prefix functions are completely supported from versions Mysql versions 5.6+. You might have to switch to newer version or go for PostGIS. For newer version of MySQL, you can go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078386/see-if-lat-long-falls-within-a-polygon-using-mysql) which will give you what you want.

Comment: yes i am looking for a solution without upgrading mysql versions